# Swift Optional error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Keeping this question up to shame myself, but no help is necessary. I just didn't understand what was going on. I thought the simulator was crashing, but it turns out I'd somehow accidentally set a breakpoint, and that was what was causing it to return to Xcode.

Feel free to ignore, but maybe leaving this up will help someone else new to Xcode.

I'm in the process of learning Swift, and taking an introductory course from lynda.com. I have run into an error that I'm sure is due to the changes in Swift since the course was produced (the instructor is on Xcode 6.0.1 while I am using 6.4). I would love some help figuring it out so I can proceed.

The example project is building a simple calculator. The step I'm on is creating the code to take a button click (any of the numbers on the calculator's UI), and display it in the UILabel that is the calculator's display.

This is the function that is apparently causing the issue:

```
var valueString:String! = ""

@IBAction func tappedNumber(sender: UIButton) {
    var str:String! = sender.titleLabel!.text
    valueString = valueString.stringByAppendingString(str)
    label.text = valueString
}
```

It doesn't show up as an error in Xcode, but when I run the simulator, when I click on one of the number buttons, the simulator crashes back to Xcode, and the line var str:String! = sender.titleLabel!.text is highlighted.

From the little bit I've already picked up, I'm guessing the error has to do with the way Swift changed how it deals with optionals. But I just don't know enough to be sure, or how to fix it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: are you sure your buttons have titleLabels with properly text field?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str:String! = sender.titleLabel?.text
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm still getting the crash after trying that. I've added a screenshot that includes the debug window after trying it your way, if that helps any.

Comment: From what I can see, the screenshot shows no crash, only a break at the breakpoint

Comment: Wow. I... totally misunderstood what was happening. I don't know how a breakpoint got set. I thought I was getting a crash. Guess I need to understand XCode better. Can I just delete this whole question in shame? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`valueString` and `str` do not need to be optionals if they are never nil.

Try:

```
var valueString: String = ""

@IBAction func tappedNumber(sender: UIButton) {
    if let label = sender.titleLabel {
        let str = label.text
        valueString = valueString.stringByAppendingString(str)
    }
    label.text = valueString
}
```